# Can't await exported async function in module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a module:

```
// sandwich.js
function getCheese(msg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){ resolve(`cheese from ${msg}`) }, 1000);
  })
}

exports.makeSandwich = async function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let response = await getCheese("Walmart")
    resolve(`sandwich from ${response}`)
  })
}
```

.. and a file that calls this module:

```
t = require('./sandwich.js')

async function eat() {
  let sandwich = await t.makeSandwich()
  console.log("ate", sandwich)
}

eat()
```

This is simple code and it *looks* fine, but when I run it I get the error:

> ```
> let response = await getCheese("Walmart")
>                      ^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

It's as if `makeSandwich` can't see the `getCheese()` method right above it in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `makeSandwich` does not need a promise inside it because the keyword `async` wraps the result in a Promise. The `await` keyword cannot be used inside a promise.

The function can be rewritten as follows:

```
exports.makeSandwich = async function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getCheese("Walmart").then(function(response) {
      resolve(`sandwich from ${response}`)
    })
 })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is a smaller example of a more complex case that I'm trying to troubleshoot. Assume that it does...

Comment: await cannot be used inside a promise, you have to use .then instead

Comment: Thanks - would be great to include supporting references (e.g. for "await cannot be used inside a promise")

Answer (score 1):

`await` can be called only from within `async` function - [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Also worth noting that if you use `await` you should use `try catch` for handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Antother solution for this problem is to add the keyword `async` to the Promise callback. Because your Promise callback Method isnt an `async` function. 
And cant use the await keyword, but with an small change this works also.
One small thing, the Promises should always be catched.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
exports.makeSandwich = async function() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
    let response = await getCheese("Walmart").catch(()=>{ /* do something */ })
    resolve(`sandwich from ${response}`)
 })
}
```

This code will also work in your case. But if someone knows if this pattern here is not a good practice, then please let me know.